# C# extend MVC MaxLengthAttribute with own error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
class MyMaxLength : MaxLengthAttribute
    {
        public static String MyErrorMessage = "Maksimalna dolžina za polje {0} je {1}";

        public MyMaxLength(int length)
        {
            new MaxLengthAttribute(length);
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ErrorMessage = MyErrorMessage;
            }
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString, name);
        }
    }
```

but I am having a problem with MyMaxLength(int length) constructor. The super class is never called. How can i create my own length validation with predefined message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for the constructor.

This is how you invoke the base constructor:

```
    public MyMaxLength(int length)
            : base(length)           // invoke the base constructor
    {

    }
```

Something else that might be worth noting is that if you are extending an attribute, while it is not mandatory, it's highly recommended to use the `Attribute` suffix. In some cases the framework will be looking for type names ending in `Attribute`.

So, your derived class might be named:

```
   class MyMaxLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
   {
        public MyMaxLengthAttribute(int length)
               : base(length)
        {
        }
```