# C# extend MVC maxlengthattribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have already searched here to answer my question, and the closest I ever got was that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022553/c-sharp-extend-mvc-maxlengthattribute-with-own-error-message), but it still does not completely clarify the matter to me, so I will ask.

What I need is extending maxlengthattribute in the way that when I set it inside the C# file,

```
[MaxLength(50)]
[Display(Name = "Project Description")]
public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
```

the attribute "maxlength" will be added inside the tag and will be <\stuff stuff maxlength = "50">

I have initially implemented it as writing html-helper to modify TextBoxFor, however, this is out of option since project is tightly intertwined with .js, and inserting renamed method will break a code, which will be a pain to fix.

The answer I referred above provides the closest explanation of what I need, but it looks like I will need to declare attributes (like inside ( ) in function), which I do not see there.

At this point I can either try modifying JS file on the server-side, or extending maxlengthattribute. Thus far, latter is preferable for me, thus I would like to ask how to properly extend it inside the c# file.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: MIght be off, but try use [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "ProjectDescription cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

Comment: @aggaton I have tried that already, however, what I need is maxlength, and physically preventing any characters beyond limit.

Comment: @riteshmeher Can you please help with the step 3 from the solution by Randhir? I do not have such file in views/shared, so I am not sure where to place it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom dataannotation provider. The max length attribute will get added to the control.
Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386365/maxlength-attribute-of-a-text-box-from-the-dataannotations-stringlength-in-asp-n)

Comment: I actually found it just before you posted it. So I will use it as an answer-reference. Thank you.

Comment: you can create folders and create ViewUserControl called string.ascx under Views\Shared\EditorTemplates